# Is it possible to run a c-media driver and the archive media driver that records the streams in the c-media driver

Tags: aeron

I have a bunch of C++ applications that want to use the low latency c-media driver for the lowest latency. There is also a need to access past messages when a new subscriber joins or an existing one crashes and restarts. Want to leverage the archiving media driver to gap fill in these scenarios.

Want to know if this setup is possible

1. run the c media driver with a local publisher and local subscribers
2. run the archive media driver to record the messages flowing in the c-media-driver
3. allow the apps to access the archive-media-driver to replay past messages and join the c-media-driver live publication

Not sure what configurations to use for setting up the two media drivers so the archiving media driver records the c-media-driver streams

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to run a C media driver and a Java media driver with associated Archive. It is also possible to run an Archive alongside a C media driver without a Java media driver. The ArchivingMediaDriver is an aggregation of an Archive and a Java MediaDriver bundled for convenience.

BTW the Java media driver is on par with the C media driver for latency and throughput when using the BSD sockets API which comes in the open source version. A significant latency reduction and throughput increase can be achieved with the kernel bypass extensions for the C driver which are available as a premium component.

Comment: thank you @martinthompson Is there a configuration to run the C media driver and the Java media driver with the associated archive in the samples?

Comment: No specific sample for this. You need to run a C media driver then start an Archive using the `aeron.dir` that is used by the C media driver.

Comment: worked great, thanks for the response @martinthompson. unable to increment the score (i have too few stackoverflow questions!)